# Removing Google Drive option in Dolphin network menu

Tags: kubuntu, drive, google, dolphin

I don't use Google Drive, don't want it, and not ever going to use it (and if so not often enough to warrant a separate icon in the network menu). I like my interface clean, so really like to get rid of it. But try as I might, I can't find an option for removing, and of course, just right click - delete doesn't work.

Anybody any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [How to mount Google Drive in KDE’s Dolphin file manager](https://blog.michael.franzl.name/2018/09/02/how-to-mount-google-drive-in-kdes-dolphin-file-manager/):

> kio-gdrive is available as a package in several Linux distributions. If installed, the Dolphin file manager will get an entry “Google Drive” under “Network”.

If I right-click on the Google Drive entry, there's a context menu apparently allowing for deleting it:

[image: Google Drive entry in Dolphin's network menu]

But that doesn't work:

[image: Cannot delete Google Drive]

However, running `sudo apt purge kio-gdrive` does the job:

[image: After purging kio-gdrive]

Comment: Super, thanks for the answer! I hadn't been searching in the right direction!

Comment: If you want, please click the ✔ near the top left of the answer to indicate the answer is accepted. Thanks!